# How to have multiple Angular apps in NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript

At my company we currently have a single project with multiple apps for each brand. Each app shares the same code base, but during the build process, only the configuration and assets (images, stylesheets) for that app/brand are used.

Now we are in the process of using this Angular project for NativeScript. Ideally it would be possible to build android and ios apps for each app/brand. Does anyone have experience with this? If so, it would be great to get your insights on how you handle this!

Comment: I am doing exactly the same. I have a script to read the last app id from package.json and based on app id I copy the specific assets and colors( .scss) to android/ios folder

Comment: I have added that as before-prepare hook so it runs every time I build the app

Comment: I have built something similar in the past where the code base was just one and only the branding (color, images, fonts, translations) may be different for each app. I created my own simple Node CLI program that will accept the brand id, I would have configuration for all brands within the project folder, copy assets for specific brand into App_Resources and then execute the tns command which would produce the right build for the brand. You may even do this with Jenkins if you are familiar.

Comment: @Manoj: Could you please share more information in order to implement this ?

Comment: Sorry, I no longer use NativeScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xplat](https://nstudio.io/xplat) or [this configuration by Dario Pellegrini](https://medium.com/@dariopellegrini/nativescript-multiple-apps-with-a-single-codebase-3abf64eb862b)